# How to import specific ID or class from a website into Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to import a specific value from a website into Google Sheets.

Example link: https://www.justetf.com/en/etf-profile.html?isin=IE00BYX2JD69#savingsplan

The value I want to import is **0.20** which is listed under fees (TER).

Does anyone know of a way to import a specific class or ID that would return the corresponding value?

Answer (score 0):

You can try these formulas:

```js
=IMPORTXML("https://www.justetf.com/en/etf-profile.html?isin=IE00BYX2JD69#savingsplan", "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[7]/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]")
```

```js
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(importxml("https://www.justetf.com/en/etf-profile.html?isin=IE00BYX2JD69#savingsplan","//div[@class='val']")),"select Col4")
```

#### Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,IMPORTXML("https://www.justetf.com/en/etf-profile.html?isin=IE00BYX2JD69#savingsplan","//div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]"),
       --regexextract(Σ,"\d+(?:\.\d+)?"))
```

[image]